# Deploying a fastai model using google app engine

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying out this example described [here](https://course.fast.ai/deployment_google_app_engine.html). I am getting this error:

```
learn.load(model_file_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/basic_train.py", line 269, in load
state = torch.load(source, map_location=device)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 529, in load
return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 692, in 
_legacy_load
magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
The command '/bin/sh -c python app/server.py' returned a non-zero code: 
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

In most sources it says, this error happens because of the download link. The link that I used is https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fz9dvsigz0yq1l/stage-2.pth?raw=1. I am also able to download it directly using the link.

Can I get some help on this?

Comment: Could you try running `gcloud app deploy` with the [verbosity set to debug](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity)? This will provide a much more detailed trace as the current trace log provided is incomplete.

Comment: I added the `verbosity` flag to the `gcloud app deploy`.  The error is below:                                                                           
     `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
      Application startup error:
      No sufficient free disk space left for your App Engine Flexible application.`

Comment: I would suggest adjusting [`disk_size_gb`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) in your `.yaml` deployment file ( usually called `app.yaml` ), in accordance to the amount of space you will be needing and see if that fixes the issue for you.